# Easiest way, if any, to host one or more linux servers on my local MacOS machine

Tags: linux, nfs

I'd like to implement a POC of one or more linux servers "sharing" a portion of their filesystem through an [exports](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exports) configuration, and an additional server mounting the exported/shared directories through `mount nfs`. I'm saying "linux" but anything with a shell and the aforementioned features would do, this is not exactly my area of expertise so maybe I'm missing some valid alternatives.

I tried googling, but the results are fairly polluted by users who just need to serve static content locally (for which you can start a basic HTTP server through the `http-server` command), and users who want to e.g. try Ubuntu on top of their Mac OS system. This second case, which as far as I understand is handled by installing an Ubuntu distribution on a VirtualBox VM, looks somewhat similar to mine, but I can't quite fill the gap.

One thing I tried is to configure the exports directories on an application server I have locally on Docker, and then tried to mount its directory in my Mac OS host, only to find out that you can't ping servers hosted in Docker containers. Perhaps I could try running multiple containers of that image and run the POC among them, within the Docker network?

Before eventually reinventing the wheel I thought I'd look for suggestions here, thank you in advance to anyone who will contribute.

Comment: Sounds like you basically want a file server that exports an NFS mount that a different (say, application) server mounts and performs some actions on/with.

Why not just spin up something like Digital Ocean droplets and configure it there? Could easily create a private network for two droplets to share and then go from there. Two very basic droplets should only run $10/mo or so. If it's just a POC it presumably wouldn't live long enough to incur big charges.

Comment: In case it matters, the actual scenario I'm trying to reproduce is: multiple application servers exporting their 'logs' directories, and a single server mounting all those 'logs' directories, this way the people who need to read the logs can do so without accessing the actual application servers. I'll look up the DigitalOcean solution you mention.

Comment: If the multiple application servers are Linux-based, I would try utilizing rsyslog and the like to automatically send them to a centralized server. It's a much more robust solution.

Besides that, it may be better to stand up something like a Graylog server and have the application servers send their logs to it. Here's some more information on [Graylog log file ingestion with filebeat.](https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/sending/files.html)

The added benefit of Graylog is it makes searching for things quite easy.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out some alternatives, I'm indeed quite prone to X-Y problems when out of my natural habitat. I'll look into rsyslog and Graylog and see if maybe I want to put up a POC of *those* instead.

Comment: @tilleyc so `rsyslog` seems indeed to be the product I'm looking for, but then my question at hand returns: is there a way to easily set up an environment where I can demonstrate a basic client-server configuration? For example in this guide https://www.rsyslog.com/sending-messages-to-a-remote-syslog-server/ they seem to have some kind of Ubuntu server on Docker. So what I'm thinking is to run 2+ containers from the official Ubuntu Docker image, and build my POC within the Docker environment. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah you could build two containers, one a dedicated syslog receiver and one an Ubuntu image that you configure to send syslog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I set up a small environment on Docker, with three ubuntu servers serving as two application servers and one "logs" server. It worked great for an `rsyslog` POC, but I couldn't make NFS work in any way, I suspect it's because some necessary service is not available on my host machine (Mac OS) and therefore Docker can't make it available on the Ubuntu servers either. For what it's worth, the `rsyslog` POC can be found [here](https://github.com/BudWhiteStudying/rsyslog-poc).